# Problem with Apache VirtualHost to run Laravel

Tags: debian, apache-virtualhost

I am trying to work with my `Laravel` installation by using a `VirtualHost` on my computer which is using `apache2` web server under debian jessie 8.5.
To do this, I first created a virtual host file named `default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and put the below text in it:

```
<VirtualHost /var/www/html/:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost /var/www/html/laravel40:8000>
    ServerName lara
    ServerAlias lara
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel40/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, after restarting the apache2 service, I can view the `localhost` easily by typing it in the browser's address bar. But with typing `lara` in the address bar, the browser shows me (chrome in my case) the results of search about the word lara. Laravel needs port `8000` to be run but I want it to run on `port 80` so that the return results of my gateway system could work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you need to make sure your DNS server would resolve `lara` to your webserver. Alternatively, editing your hosts file could do.

then, defining a virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost /var/www/html/laravel40:8000>
```

Should probably be replaced with

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8000>
<VirtualHost fqdn:8000>
or <VirtualHost *:8000>
```

Also: just adding a virtualhost won't configure apache to listen on a new port. Look for `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` of your main apache configuration file, there should be some `Listen 80` already present, make sure to add `Listen 8000` somewhere in there.

Finally: if your browser starts searching when you type a short name that your DNS should resolve, you could try adding the protocol prefix (`http://` or `https://`). If you need to connect to port 8000, then make sure to type it in as well.